# Validating user defaults when using NSDictionaryController and Swift

Tags: swift, cocoa-bindings

I have a view-based table with an NSDictionaryController, the content of which is bound to NSUserDefaultsController in Interface Builder:

[image: Content binding]

What is the correct way of validating the dictionary values in Swift? (The dictionary keys are automatically validated, and an error is raised for empty keys. I want to do the same for the dictionary values.)

Comment: Can a value in a dictionary be nil? Do you want to validate the values in the dictionary before display or do you want to validate user input?

Comment: @Willeke I want to validate user input. The values in the dictionary can't be nil.

Answer (score 0):

Set the delegate of the text field in the cell to the delegate of the table view and implement `control(_:isValidObject:)`.

Comment: It seems `control(_:isValidObject:)` is not called if I just leave the value empty. On the other hand, if I first edit the value and then try to leave it empty, `control(_:isValidObject:)` is called if I uncheck *Validates Immediately* in the Bindings Inspector. If *Validates Immediately* is checked, I get a modal sheet with "Value for _key_ cannot be empty. Please provide a valid value." instead. Can I validate when no edit is made and the NSTextField loses focus?

Comment: From the documentation of `NSDictionaryController`: "You must enable the “Validates Immediately” option for the value binding of all controls that edit the key names or values returned by arrangedObjects.". How do you end up with an empty value?

Comment: When I add a new token with the `NSDictionaryController` method `add(_:)`, the key is generated automatically but the value is empty. (The _tokens_ dictionary is of type `[String: String]`.)

Comment: Is "Validates Immediately" of the text field in the value column switched on?

Comment: _Validates immediately_ has no effect when the text field is just opened and dismissed without typing. However, if I start typing but then delete the contents, I get a modal sheet at the end of editing if _Validates immediately_ is checked. If it is not, `control(_:isValidObject:)` is called.

Comment: If you don't change anything, the value is valid.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to implement a function as follows:

```
@objc func validateToken(_ ioValue: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<AnyObject?>) throws {
    guard ioValue.pointee != nil else {
        // throw some error
    }
}
```

Your Cocoa Binding will look for that function via validateValue(_:forKey:).

> For it to be found, the property specific validation function must be exposed to Objective-C, must be named according to the pattern validate*InKey*, must take a single, optional AnyObject pointer argument, and must throw (Apple Inc., 2018).

I am assuming that your binding points to a specific value in your dictionary.

Reference:

Apple Inc. (2018). validateValue(_:forKey:). Retrieved from https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1416754-validatevalue